# Understanding Traits vs Composition in PHP

Tags: php, traits

I was trying to research the topic of using traits, and I can't seem to get a definite answer.

The blogger ircmaxell suggests they [might be "the new eval"](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/07/are-traits-new-eval.html), and I found other sites [like this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-traits-good-or-bad/), speaking good and bad about them. I want to make sure I am understanding how they work correctly, before implementing them in my project.

For example:
I have 10 different classes that all extend one Parent, and each class has 20 methods. There might be an overlap of 5 methods between half of the classes, so wouldn't it make sense to abstract those 5 methods into traits? The point of traits is so the methods can be applied to the classes that need them, without polluting the other classes that don't need them by putting them in the parent, correct?

```
// Why repeat myself?
class Parent {
    public method1() {}
    public method2() {}
    public method3() {}
}

class Foo extends Parent {
    public specificMethod1() {}    
    public specificMethod2() {}    
    public commonMethod1() {}
}

class Bar extends Parent {
    public specificMethod1() {}    
    public specificMethod2() {}
}

class Baz extends Parent {
    public specificMethod1() {}    
    public specificMethod2() {}    
    public commonMethod1() {}
}

// This way makes more sense
trait commonMethod1 {
    public commonMethod1() {}   
}

class Foo extends Parent {
    use commonMethod1;
    public specificMethod1() {}    
    public specificMethod2() {}
}

class Bar extends Parent {
    public specificMethod1() {}    
    public specificMethod2() {}
}

class Baz extends Parent {
    use commonMethod1;
    public specificMethod1() {}    
    public specificMethod2() {}
}
```

Comment: In your example, wouldn't `specificMethod1` and `specificMethod2` be best in the Parent? They are common to all child classes.

Comment: Whether to use traits or not in a particular case is subjective. In this case, a three-level hierarchy might be more appropriate: a parent could be extended once to include `commonMethod1`, and then extended again for `Foo` and `Baz`. (Abstract examples are harder to make sense of though, since there is no discernible relationship as there is with, say, Vehicle, Car and Hatchback).

Comment: Traits are language assisted copy paste. There are numerous cases where they are useful. In the case you mentioned, they make *perfect sense*. Some classes need those 5 methods, some don't, but they all stem from the same `Parent`. A trait allows you to write those 5 methods once and "inject" them into the classes requiring them.

Comment: @halfer The reason I don't want to add them to the parent is because that was just a short example. In my actual project, I have more like 15 classes, that share a handful of methods, between each other. Like class A and B need method 3 and 8, but C and D need 2 and 5, on top of that E needs 1,2,3,5,8 and F might need 1,2,8,9. I have been copy pasting the methods around, but once I read about traits, it seemed like my perfect use case.

Comment: It might be worth adding a short note of a similar nature to your question, in that case (I think it's correct that you added a simplified example, but it is worth noting its limitations too). I like traits, and I use them myself, but for your example it would not be necessary.

Comment: Incidentally, I have a use case for traits at the moment, where traditional vertical inheritance is not possible, since all parent classes are created by a code generator. I don't know how much it relates to your specific problem, but do let me know if you would like me to post an answer as a more general answer to when traits can be useful?

Comment: Thank you for your input, it sounds like traits are exactly what I need and will save me lots of time manually copy pasting methods around. I just wish I started with them so I don't have to go back and refactor my current classes. It will save me time in the future, for new classes that need the methods, and make it easier to update any class that uses them. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right. You can get main benefit from traits  when you will need some kind of multi-inheritance, that is not supported by PHP. So you can organize some code that is supposed to be reused in different classes, that has not inheritance relation.

For example: You can have a class "Other" that is not related to Partent, but you still need the function "commonMethod1", so you can use same trait

```
class Other {
use commonMethod1; 
}
```